# Youtube Video -Blank Screen appers in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I am adding video in recyclerview  as a first item. Whenever i scroll down, they video is not pausing which should happen.and when i scroll up, audio is just playing ,for video it's just show empty screen